# WPF Application in POS terminals

Tags: wpf, optimization

Im working on application for POS terminals with specification like this one:

```
CPU Support     Intel Pineview D525 Duo Core, 1.8G, L2 1M FSB667/800MHz
Chipset     CPU integrated graphic + ICH8M
System Memory   1 x DDR3 SO-DIMM socket up to 2GB
Graphic Memory  Intel GMA 3150 share system memory up to 256MB
```

They dont really have any active cooling, and when someone works on it for like 5-7 hours (with wpf app still running), they get really hot and work slow - for example relogginng user in system (with ado connection, and simply select user where name = entered string) sometime takes like 2 minutes. 
Here is my question - is it possible to somehow optimize wpf application (for example turn some function off)? I checked that cpu usage is ~25%, application doesnt also take much of ram memory. Maybe there is problem with graphic card? Bad thing is that, POS after that 5-7 hours shows on sensor 100*C (+ -), and becouse of that everything work slow (even opening my computer etc.).

Comment: when i read the title i thought that "did i write this post" ? It does lag but maybe you are using too much cpu. I run a exact similar POS for 6 months 24/7 no shutdown and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to tune an application for low power but there is no magic switch to do it.

You will need to remove effects to make it as simple as possible. I'd guess that these are in order, but you might have to compare CPU usage over several runs

- Remove animation, as this requires constant recalculation of the pixels to show
- Remove opacity, as the GPU has to calculate what is shown through it
- Remove gradients, as they need every colour calculating
- Use only a single full screen window, as avoiding any overlapping drops the calculation of which areas should be clipped or not.
- And finally try and stick to square shapes as this requires the simplest resolution of areas

If this sounds remarkably like the new Windows 8 Apps, then that's because Win8 Apps have to be able to run on really low power tablets too.

Also in your backend, you might be to cache data and avoid having to keep connecting to a server.